# Copytruncate functionality without using logrotate

Tags: shell-script, logs, logrotate

Is there something that allows me to move just the content of a file, and save it in another file? I know there is copytruncate, but I can't use logrotate in my setup. The file the content is moved from, has to stay as it is. Just the lines written would be transferred to another file. I need something that i can put in a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way but you can try

```
cat file > new_file
truncate -s0 file
```

If the files are huge then you should keep looking for a better way.

Comment: Why wouldnt it work with huge files ?

Comment: The copying of data will take some time and if it is more than a few milliseconds, new data would be written to the file before truncate call is triggered. In case of huge files it can take seconds.

Comment: If new Data would be coming in during the clearing, if thats whats you mean, that would be fine. Its a logfile in whitch is constantly in use

Comment: You may use it then. I just wanted you to know the shortcomings of the script.

Comment: So I tried you suggestion, and it seems to work, but there is one thing. All the Data that has been copied away has now been replaced with a @ in my test enviroment. Any idea why that is ?

Answer (score 0):

For any new curiosity mongers:

```
:> filename
```

Seen [here](https://linuxize.com/post/truncate-files-in-linux/).